# Naming and grammar: getResultsCount or getResultCount?

Tags: naming

When writing API methods that count something I always lose a tremendous amount of time thinking about how to write the thing that is being counted.

Singular or plural?

For instance, how would you name a function that counts results?

`getResultsCount` or `getResultCount` ?

This might sound silly, plural sounds more logical, but since both forms are found in the wild (google gives ~4800 results for "`getResultCount`" and ~4600 for "`getResultsCount`"), I'm hesitating and it bothers me.

Disclaimer: I'm not a native English speaker :)

Is there only one grammatically correct form or is it a matter of taste?

Answer (score 0):

You should naming it basically for what it will do, if `getResultsCount` make mores sense than `getResultCount`, name it `getResultsCount`, else, name it `getResultCount`.

Its not that hard, Ill you have to do is give name that sweets better accordinling to the what it will do.

I suggest you read the book Clean Code written by Robert C. Martin, it really give good tips about naming.